# Input Textfield date mask

Tags: actionscript-3, date, input

I need to restrict my users to input only dates with a custom format. I want to have something like this example in JQuery: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMaTiGKykl8&feature=player_embedded

How can i archieved this in AS3?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to catch the KeyPressed event on the TextField. Check if the key pressed is OK at the specified position, if yes, do nothing, if not, cancel the event (Event.cancel = true).

Alternatively (for more features, like these auto added slashes) you can ALWAYS cancel the Event, and use the TextField's selection together with a String and some checking to always make a new version of the TextField's text.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a DateField and format the data as you see fit?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2